# PHP - Mod_rewrite with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about mod_rewrite - I have the following URL:

```
http://website.com/profile/index.php?a=profile&u=username
```

I am trying to rewrite that to:

```
http://website.com/profile/user/username
```

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/profile/user/([^/]*)$ /profile/index.php&a=profile&u=$1 [L]
```

Although when going to the rewritten URL, I don't see that page. I just see the default index.php page. I tried getting the paramters by printing: `print_r($_GET);`

Which gave me the following:

```
Array ( [a] => u [q] => /username)
```

Now my question is - how can I rewrite the first URL to the second? Apparently, the `a` is empty and the `u` also contains a `/`

Comment: Would you try: `RewriteRule ^/profile/user/([^/]*)$ /index.php&a=$1&u=$2 [L]`

Comment: @Testing then the  `a` parameter becomes `user` - should be  `profile` in order for the index.php page to get the correct file.

Comment: See my edit above.. @oliverbj

Comment: Why you have "&a=profile&u=$1"? I think you should have ?a=profile&u=$1.  "?" instead of "&". (in your htaccess).

Comment: @Testing the a parameter is still user - you changed a to be $1 - but user is still declared.

Comment: @Kristiyan Thanks for pointing that out - changed that in my code, but still no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/user/([^/]*)$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]
```

For url: `localhost/profile/user/test` - `print_r($_GET)` return:

```
Array ( [a] => profile [u] => test )
```

Answer (score -2):

Mode_rewrite

try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^$              [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^query=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/old-search$       /search/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^view=tags$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog$             /profile/users/     [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^view=posts$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog$             /profile/          [NC,L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^/profile$  /profile/%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you really this it will fulfill requirements of OP?

Comment: @Aelmasry what's with the "old-search" and "blog"?